# Triggering "select" query in Laravel returns NULL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm starting to learn Laravel, but not surprisingly, I'm bumping into problems. This one I know is basic, but I can't solve. I'm trying to make a simple SELECT from the database but it shows nothing!

This is the code

web.php

```
Route::get('list', ['uses' => 'robotController@index']);
```

robotController

```
public function index()
{
    $robots = DB::select('select * from robots where Name = ?', [1]);
    return view('ListaRobots', ['robots' => $robots]);
}
```

listaRobots.blade.php

```
@foreach ($robots as $robot) {{ $robot['Name'] }} @endforeach
```

I'm trying to make a foreach that gets the "Name" of all the robots but I can't get anything. The screen goes all blank. But I have two entries in the robots table. I have changed the .env to connect to the DB, and managed to use seed to create entries in the table but cant make queries.

Comment: You're selecting only robots which have the name `1`.

Comment: I tried that before (putting 1 to the name) and then i get this error: "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to get a list of robots by name. So change a few things.

Routes:

```
Route::get('/robots/{name}', ['uses' => 'robotController@show']);
```

Controller:

```
function show($name) {
    $robots = DB::table('robots')->where('name', '=', $name)->get();
    return view('ListaRobots', ['robots' => $robots]);
}
```

Comment: m getting the error "NotFoundHttpException" and a warning that the page doesnt exist. I have tried to replace the {name}, but no matter what i do, im always getting this error.

Comment: That error is because is missing a `:` between `Route` and `get()`. I edited the answer.

Comment: Actually i had noticed that mistake and corrected it. I had to correct the listarobots file. Now im starting to get data from it. But without you, i would never get anything. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1):

You are selecting all rows where `Name` equals `1`.
Are you sure that's what you want?

You might want to rename `Name` to `id`.

Comment: I do that and It still gets the error: "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array".